# Python raw_input() infinite loop with if statements and while loop

Tags: python

I do not know how to make the loop, but somebody told me about it. Here is a similar code:

```
one = True
two = False
three = False

typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
    #first
if one == True and two == False and three == False:
    if typed_input == "blah":
        do something
        typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
        one = False
        two = True
        three = False

    elif "the" in typed_input:
        do something else
        typed_input = raw_input("Type here: ")
        one = False
        two = True
        three = False
```

By the way, don't take this down because though it may appear to be a copy, the question that it may seem like did not help me in any way. I need something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is a while True to start your loop, and then you need to only do what you did above with two of your input checkers copied instead of having hundreds of them just to simulate a conversation. Do while at the outside, then the if one two three in the next indent, and then do your chat checking